# Android Studio 2.3.1 Dead Slow after update from 2.2.3

Tags: android, android-studio

I have recently upgraded my Android Studio 2.2.3 to 2.3.1, Now everything in Android studio is hanging from very low level task like copy paste to gradle sync takes a lot of time and it looks very unstable version.

Can I revert to old version i.e Android 2.2.3 ? please help.